# Minizinc array sorting

Tags: sorting, minizinc

Lets say I have an array declaration looking like this

```
array[1..5] of int: temp = [1,0,5,0,3];
```

Is there a way to initiate a new array looking the same as temp but without the 0's? The result would look like the following

```
[1,5,3]
```

or sort the array in such a way that the 0's would be either in the beginning or in the end of the array, which would be

```
[0,0,1,5,3]
```

or

```
[1,5,3,0,0]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though Axel has answered this, I'll show another approach which - in my book is a little neater.

- Case 1: the array ("temp") is a constant array.
  Then one can simply write

  array[int] of int: temp2 = [temp[i] | i in index_set(temp) where temp[i] != 0];

MiniZinc 2 (in contrast to version 1.*) don't need the size declaration if it can be calculated; it suffices to just use "array[int]". Also, "index_set" is used to be a little more general, e.g. to handle cases where the indices are from 0..4 (see the commented line).

- Case 2: the array ("s") is an array of decision variables

If the array to handle is decision variables, we don't know (per definition) how many 0's there are and must rely on the alternative variant, namely to sort the array. One can then use the "sort" function, as shown in the model.

```
 include "globals.mzn";

 % constant
 array[1..5] of int: temp = [1,0,5,0,3];
 % array[0..4] of int: temp = array1d(0..4, [1,0,5,0,3]);
 array[int] of int: temp2 = [temp[i] | i in index_set(temp) where temp[i] != 0];

 % decision variables
 array[1..5] of var int: s;
 array[1..5] of var int: s2 = sort(s); % NOT CORRECT, see model below

 solve satisfy;

 constraint
    s = [1,0,5,0,3]
 ;

 %  show our variables
 output 
 [
    "temp: \(temp)\n",
    "temp2: \(temp2)\n",

    "s: \(s)\n",
    "s2: \(s2)\n",
 ];
```

**Update**

For the stable version of decision variables, this works what I can see. It calculating the position where to place this number depending on if "s[i]" is 0 or not. Not very pretty though.

```
 int: n = 5;
 array[1..n] of var 0..5: s;
 array[1..n] of var lb_array(s)..ub_array(s): s2;

 solve satisfy;

 constraint
   s = [1,0,5,0,3] /\
   forall(i in 1..n) (
      if s[i] != 0 then
        s2[sum([s[j]!=0 | j in 1..i-1])+1] = s[i]
      else 
        s2[sum([s[j]!=0 | j in 1..n]) + sum([s[j]=0 | j in 1..i-1])+1 ] = 0
      endif
   )
;

output 
[ 
  "s: \(s)\n",
  "s2: \(s2)\n",
]
;
```

The output is

```
s: [1, 0, 5, 0, 3]
s2: [1, 5, 3, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the explanations. In my case it is important to keep the order of the non-zero-elements in s. I.e. I would want s2 to be [0,0,1,5,3]. Is it possible to achieve this even though s is an array of decision variables?

Comment: Ah, I missed this requirement. The answer now contains a variant for solving this, though the answer is [1,5,3,0,0] instead of [0,0,1,5,3].

Comment: Note: I updated the code to be slightly more general by using "int: n = 5", and changed the domain of "s2" to be in the same range as "s" which is in general better for the solvers.

Comment: I have now generalized the second model further with functions etc: http://hakank.org/minizinc/separate_zeros.mzn

Comment: Thanks a alot. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Using `MiniZinc 2`, this can be done as follows:

```
array[1..5] of int: temp = [1,0,5,0,3];
%  calculate upper bound of temp index
int: i_max = max(index_set(temp));
%  use array comprehension to count non-zero elements
int: temp_non_zero = sum([1 | i in 1..i_max where temp[i] != 0]);
%  copy non-zero elements to new array
array[1..temp_non_zero] of int: temp2 = [temp[i] | i in 1..i_max where temp[i] != 0];
%  calculate upper bound for temp2 index
int: i2_max = max(index_set(temp2));

solve satisfy;

%  show our variables
output 
["\ni_max=" ++ show(i_max)] 
++ ["\ni2_max=" ++ show(i2_max)] 
++ ["\n" ++ show(temp2[i]) | i in 1..i2_max] 
;
```

Comment: Thanks. How would one do if temp was an array of decision variables? With this approach I get the type error: initialisation value for `temp2' has invalid type-inst: expected `array[int] of int', actual `array[int] of var opt int'. Maybe this question is more suitable as a new post if it requires a totally different model?

Comment: To keep an array of decision variables sorted, you have to define a constraint which enforces that ever array element is smaller/greater than its neighbour.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative:

A 1:1 mapping between the two arrays is established as an array of unique index values (= array positions). These indices are then sorted. The comparison weights elements higher if they point to a zero. Thus, the zero values are shifted to the back while leaving the order of the non-zero elements unchanged.

```
int: n = 5;
int: INF = 99999;    %  infinity
array[1..n] of var 0..5: s;
array[1..n] of var 1..n: map;
array[1..n] of var 0..5: s2;

solve satisfy;

%  set s[]
constraint
   s = [1,0,5,0,3]
;
%  1:1 mapping between s[] and s2[]
constraint 
  forall (i in 1..n) (
    exists(j in 1..n) (
      map[j] = i
    )
  )
;
constraint
   forall(i in 1..n) (
      s2[i] = s[map[i]]
   )
;
%  sort the map and move zero values to the back
constraint
   forall(i in 1..n-1) (
     (if s2[i] != 0 then map[i] else INF endif) <= 
     (if s2[i+1] != 0 then map[i+1] else INF endif)
   )
;

output 
[ 
  "s: \(s)\n",
  "map: \(map)\n",
  "s2: \(s2)\n",
]
;
```

Output:

```
s: [1, 0, 5, 0, 3]
map: [1, 3, 5, 4, 2]
s2: [1, 5, 3, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Hi Axel. Note that this model has 6 different solutions and it don't keep the order of the non zero values. E.g., one solution is [0,1,3,5,5] which is not correct. I.e. the objective is not really to "sort" the array, it's rather to separate zeros from non-zero values.

Comment: Hi Axel. Ah, I was not very clear. 1) Your solution in the answer is not correct according to the "stable" criteria, i.e. that the non-zero values should be in the same order as in the "s" array. 2) The solution you showed is not the only solution. There are 5 more solutions for your model and they are not correct either: [0, 1, 1, 3, 5], [0, 1, 2, 3, 5], [0, 1, 3, 3, 5],  [0, 1, 3, 4, 5], [0, 1, 3, 5, 5]. My model - ugly as it is - give just a unique solution: [1, 5, 3, 0, 0].

Comment: Hi Axel. To get all solutions, you can add the -a option to the solver (note that MIP solvers only shows just one solution). The problem is that you only select the specific values (0,1,3, and 5) to be in "s2", but not the exact number of occurrences. That's why there are two 1's, two 3's, or two 5's in the solutions. Using the "count" constraint would have fixed the occurrence problem: "forall(i in 1..n) (count(s,i) = coun(s2,i) )". A "sort" constraint would have been enough for getting an unique and sorted solution, though we now know it was not really a sorting problem.